# PHP: Duplicate entry 'xx' for key 'yy'

Tags: php, mysql, duplicate-data

I get the following error:

```
Duplicate entry 'morandi-midnight-train' for key 'post_name'
```

I want to check if post_name field has already a  row defined with a variable and echo an error if it does.

How can i acomplish this?

- post_name has a unique index

Comment: well... i want to control that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE post_name = 'morandi-midnight-train' LIMIT 1;` before your INSERT query. If the SELECT has any results, show the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want check the presence of a row you can just do SELECT.

But this is not the best way to avoid "Duplicated key" problem. Perhaps it will be better for you to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in your insert operation. This will insert a new row if it doesn't exist or silently update the existing row if it exists.

See the MySQL manual for details:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score -1):

If you want to ignore the error, run an `INSERT IGNORE...` and check for affected rows afterwards (via `mysql_affected_rows()`).

If you want to update a record which has been inserted already, run a `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query.

See [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)